# How to display something in HAML only if it exists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have an environment variable:

```
ONETRUST_SRC: 'https://somesite'
```

I tried:

```
- if ENV['ONETRUST_SRC']?
  = javascript_include_tag ENV['ONETRUST_SRC']
  :javascript
    function myfunc() { }
```

That's giving me a weird error:

```
syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ':'
```

Comment: I suspect the `?` is causing the issue. Change it to `- if ENV['ONETRUST_SRC'].present?`

Comment: Make it an answer and I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trailing `?` is causing this error (The `expecting ':'` is because the `?` is being interpreted as a ternary operator in this case).

Change your if statement to use [`present?`](https://apidock.com/rails/Object/present%3F):

```
- if ENV['ONETRUST_SRC'].present?
  = javascript_include_tag ENV['ONETRUST_SRC']
  :javascript
    function myfunc() { }
```